# React Native: How to change the status bar style depending on the Scroll or Y contentOffset

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

Hello React Native developers !

I would like to change the style of the status bar depending on the scroll position. For exemple switching from "light-content" to "dark-content" when reaching a certain point in the view.

My "solution" was to read to Y contentOffset and use `setState` to switch to `true` or `false`. Problem is that it during the `setState`, the animation will stutter. Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem ?

Thank you !

```
const HomeComponent = () => {
  const [isLightStatusBar, setIsLightStatusBar] = useState(true);

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 250 && isLightStatusBar) {
      setIsLightStatusBar(false);
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < 250 && !isLightStatusBar) {
      setIsLightStatusBar(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={`${isLightStatusBar ? "light-content" : "dark-content"}`}
      />
      <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16} onScroll={handleScroll}>
        {/* SOME COMPONENTS */}
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: did you try to separate two components?
you have the whole list that re-renders based on its scroll position. But what you need - is to re-render the status bar. I would split them and pass a Y-position as a parameter to StatusBar, and it will decide what to do on its own

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the idea but how would you pass the value of `y` as a prop without saving this value in a state beforehand in this example?

Comment: you simply define a variable that's not a state variable

Comment: ok so in your case, you can try : define a variable `const yPosition = 0`
pass it as a parameter to `StatusBar`, handle change inside `StatusBar`
set this variable in `handleScroll`
this way you (hopefuly) don't update state and avoid re-rendering

Answer (score 0):

following our conversation in the comments:

```js
const HomeComponent = () => {
  const yPosition = 0;

  const handleScroll = (e) => { yPosition = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar
        yPosition={yPosition}
      />
      <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16} onScroll={handleScroll}>
        {/* SOME COMPONENTS */}
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
};
```